# Script inserts literal * instead of wildcard ONLY during boot

Tags: raspbian, linux, raspbian-stretch, bash

This has driven me crazy so I hope someone can help.  I have a script that works perfectly when executed manually or when restarting lightdm, but when it runs during a boot and auto-login, it returns a literal * instead of using it as a wildcard.  It is set to run from

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

by including:

```
@/bin/sh /home/pi/finder.sh
```

the script includes:

```
fileName=( /media/pi/DISPLAY/display.* )
[[ -e $fileName ]]
```

I have used other iterations of code and search methods, but all have the same results.  When this script is run under any circumstances other than a boot/login it returns a $fileName something like:

```
/media/pi/DISPLAY/display.txt
```

or

```
/media/pi/DISPLAY/display.ppt
```

However, when the pi boots and performs its auto-login, it returns the exact $fileName of:

```
/media/pi/DISPLAY/display.*
```

I have tried any number of alernative coding solutions, and even started with a simple find command.  However, everything I do has the same results of working with:

```
./finder.sh
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

but nothing I have tried works during the normal boot process and always returns a literal * instead of wilcard results.

Comment: i'm only guessing here.  it may be that the boot-time shell is different from run-time shell

Answer (score 1):

The shell is run with turned-off globbing, most likely for "security reasons".

```
$ ls -1
a
b
$ echo *
a b
$ set -f
$ echo *
*
$ set +f
$ echo *
a b
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get "/media/pi/DISPLAY/display.*" when there is no file corresponding.